# Nominalisation: gerund v present participle help

Tags: participles, gerund

I’m having real difficulty identifying whether a word has been nominalised or not.  Whether it’s acting as a noun or is a present particle.  The instances in the text I’m working on are ambiguous (at least to me). I understand the concept of nominalisations and know the difference between a gerund and present participle but I can’t decide which ones they are in my text.
Any suggestions on how I can establish which it is?  Some kind of test or tip perhaps.
Thanks x

Comment: What language are you working on? If it's English, you should be asking in the English Language and Usage stack exchange, not Linguistics. We don't do individual language grammar here. And if you give some examples, you might be understood; technical terminology doesn't always mean what we might expect it to.

Comment: Oh I see.  I’m sorry, I’m new here. 
It was in relation to analysing textual metafunction.  I trying to tie in my question with post modification.

Comment: Use a lot of examples, then, to show what you're referring to when you post at ELU.SE. It's hard to tell, for instance, that _duck_ and _hammer_ are verbs that nominalize, whereas _nail_ is a noun that verbalizes. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: It’s quite a lengthy academic text so I’ll have to extract the instances.  Some are very ambiguous so I don’t want mess up my statistics by categorising them incorrectly.  I think study fatigue isn’t helping either :(

Comment: His ducking did not save him from the bullet.   She could not stand his hammering all night.   Would these be examples?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann "Ducking" and "hammering" are not nouns in your examples but verbs, or at least ambiguous between the two. Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "his constant ducking / hammering". Also, they can take an NP complement "his ducking the issue".